# what can I use sed to search for a string and append /sub1 and some file ../ before search string

Tags: linux, unix, replace, sed

I have to look through jsp file and look for for string loginpage.jsp and replace with ../loginPage.jsp.
I have tried following:
 1st try:

```
    sed -i -e 's/<a id="logo" href="loginPage.jsp"><span class="alt">abc</span>        </a>/<a      id="logo" href="../loginPage.jsp"><span class="alt">abc</span></a>/g'
```

2nd try:

```
    SRC="'loginPage.jsp'"
    DEST="'sub2/loginPage.jsp'"
    sed -i "s/$SRC/$DEST/g" <file path>/test1.jsp
```

3rd try using line number is file

```
   var="response.sendRedirect("sub2/loginPage.jsp");"
   sed "19 s/.*/$var/" <file path>/test1.jsp
```

Could you please guide me how to achieve this?
Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since your input text has slash too, you should either escape all slashes in your input or use another separator, for example, try these:

```
sed 's#<....>#replacement#g' file
```

or

```
sed -i "s#$SRC#$DEST#g" <file path>/test1.jsp
```

Comment: I have tried SRC="'loginPage.jsp'"
DEST="'sub2/loginPage.jsp'" and tried sed -i "s#$SRC#$DEST#g" <file path>/test1.jsp, it is not throwing any error but it is not updating the file. Do, you see any error how I am passing the value for variables SRC and DEST?

Comment: @Urmi first try very simple examples. you will see the vars are passed to sed. I see you have `'`(single quote) wrapping login.jsp. are those chars in your file?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I see your main problem is using / as a delimiter in sed command.
In sed you can use almost any character for this purpose, so **sed "s-aa-bb-"** works fine. In your case, as the replacement has a / sed itself gets confued and the rest of the string is not parsed.

from the sed's manual:

> *\***c***regexp***c**
>
> ```
>          Match lines matching the regular expression regexp.  The  c  may  be  any
>          character
> ```

Answer (score 0):

As well as the delimiter issues mentioned by Kent and chapuzzo,
I suspect the way you are quoting could also be the problem.
Especially relevant if you're working with a version of 'sed'
that isn't the same as we're all using.

This simple approach worked for me (Ubuntu, standard gnu sed):

```
% cat foo3
<a id="logo" href="loginPage.jsp"><span class="alt">abc</span>
% sed -e 's=loginPage.jsp=sub2/loginPage.jsp=' < foo3
<a id="logo" href="sub2/loginPage.jsp"><span class="alt">abc</span>
% sed --ver
GNU sed version 4.2.1
```

And a PS, it's not clear why you are using -i flag, and it might
not be doing what you think/expect.